# gnome-shell spamming on /var/log/syslog

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, syslog, gnome-shell

Moved from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061925/gnome-shell-spamming-on-var-log-syslog because it was closed there without a solution; and it's also currently happening to me (I am running Ubuntu 20.10 but there's no tag for that)

---

I see a lot of logs in /var/log/syslog, so i have thinked about a redirecting the output of gnome-shell logs to /dev/null using rsyslog, I do not edit the default configuration file in /etc/rsyslog.conf creating the 00-my-file.conf custom file into /etc/rsyslog.d/ into the file that i created i written the following code

if $msg contains 'deallocated' then /dev/null

But it do now works. The gnome log print strings with 'deallocated' an example of gnome log is

```
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e32619b220 ==
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: #0   7fff4e657410 I   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:2051 (2a458f8a6330 @ 208)
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: Object St.Bin (0x55e32b1423a0), has been already deallocated — impossible to set any property on it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: Object St.Bin (0x55e32a03fc80), has been already deallocated — impossible to set any property on it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: Object St.Bin (0x55e328c92fa0), has been already deallocated — impossible to set any property on it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: Object St.Bin (0x55e328f19080), has been already deallocated — impossible to set any property on it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Feb  5 11:49:26 HP gnome-shell[1608]: Object St.Bin (0x55e326ea8480), has been already deallocated — impossible to set any property on it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
```

If you know know you solve gnome-shell issue, please tell me a possible solution. Please help me, i'll read all replies.

Comment: @daniele-romanella Welcome to the Stack Exchange community. Unfortunately your post was deleted on StackExchange without pointing you to the right forum. I copied the post here for  where it is valid. Thanks for posting your question, and keep them coming!

Comment: Restarting gnome-shell failed for me `killall -SIGQUIT gnome-shell` - (don't) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/100226/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command-line

Comment: I tried `apt update` then `apt upgrade` there was no improvement

Comment: System restart didn't fix it. Note: the release for the fix on package gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock seems to be 1 month ago - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1905519/comments/12

Comment: The gnome-shell restart solution actually did work, I was just using the wrong method to view the tail of the logs before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For some people](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1905519/comments/5), restarting gnome-shell resolves the issue.

- Press key combination: ALT+F2
- A command popup will appear
- Type 'r', press ENTER

---

According to [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1905519/comments/4), the problem is caused by the following steps:

i found a way to reproduce

- wait for an automatic update manager prompt
- apply the updates (in the dock, the update-manager icon is twisting)
- when its done, close update-manager
- then the error start to appear in syslog

Comment: This did work actually, I just didn't realise that `cat /var/log/syslog` went so far back I'll use `journalctl -xe` instead